# Legend problems with 2 y axis in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a 2 y axis plot with the left axis has a bar graph and the right axis has 2 line graphs. I am having difficulty getting the legend to have both the bar and line graphs on it. I can plot the legends separately but I would like to have them together. Here is the work I have done so far.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
x = df["date"]
y1 = df["line 1"]
y2 = df["line 2"]
z = df["bar 1"]
y_pos = np.arange(len(x))

lns1 = plt.bar(y_pos,z)
plt.ylabel('bar 1')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.legend([lns1], ["bar 1"])
plt.twinx()
lns2 = plt.plot(y_pos,y1,'r-',linewidth=2.5)
lns3 = plt.plot(y_pos,y2,color='orange',linewidth=2.5)
plt.ylabel('L-SLOC')
plt.xticks(y_pos, x)
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.title('Title of graph')

plt.legend(["line 1", "line 2"],loc="upper left")


plt.draw()
plt.show()`
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
plt.legend([lns1], ["bar 1"])
```

and

```
plt.legend(["line 1", "line 2"],loc="upper left")
```

You could try this:

```
plt.legend([lns1, lns2, lns3], ["bar 1", "line 1", "line 2"],loc="upper left")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only shows the bar graph and does not add in the line graphs.

Comment: Could you share your csv? I need it to try your code

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload that data but here it is.                                  (date, line 1, line 2, bar 1)
(11/17/2015, 12, 60, 0.22)
(12/13/2015, 19, 34, 0.153)
(01/12/2016, 12, 70, 0.12)
(2/7/2016, 100, 56, 0.313)
(5/30/2016, 50, 95, 0.175)

Comment: You need to select the line from the list, i.e. `plt.legend([lns1, lns2[0], lns3[0]], ["bar 1", "line 1", "line 2"],loc="upper left")`. Or maybe better define `lns2` and `lns3` like `ln2, = plt.plot(...)` (note the comma) and use the solution from the answer.